# Problems debugging (breakpoints not being hit)

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2010

I'm facing problems when i try to debugging with Visual Studio 2010.
My breakpoints don't work and gives the message: 
*The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  The source code is different then the original version*

I've go to tools and enabled "Enable Just My Code" but now i get the message: 
*Breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols  loaded for this document*

I've delete the obj folder, with no success.
I've used the "Clean Solution", i've Rebuild Solution, and so on.

What should i do more to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try an iisreset? Maybe an old version of your assembly is still in cache?

Comment: Have you closed the internal Visual Studio web server?

Comment: I've restarted the IIS, closed the web server of VS, etc.

When i run the debug, in "Modules" windows there doesn't show an dll that i'm using from an project (my solution has 3 projects).
I remember that this had happen before, and when i've fixed it the dll of the project shows up again in module window, but now i can't solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the projects it's debugging successfully. I've just changed the ports of Web Server.

But other project (i've changed the ports too) still doesn't work. The message of this one is:
**the breakpoint will not be hit. the source code is diferent from the original**

Comment: Well i've disabled the "Require Source files to exactly match the original version" and now it's debugging.

But is this recommended? What difference makes to debugging?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

Trying changing the debug attribute of the compilation tag in the web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true">
```